# PHP header('Location: index.php') not working after turning on HTTPS

Tags: php, https, header, location

After enabling HTTPS on the website my location headers don't respond anymore. Never had this problem before.

I've tried different thing to fix it, but it still won't work

```
<?php
include('check.php');

header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
if(empty($_SESSION)){


} else {
    header("Location: http://example.com/admin.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: have you tried fixing your non-SSL location header? Add an s!

Answer (score 0):

`header("Location: http://example.com/admin.php");` should be the first output done in a script ..

You need to remove the `header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");` statement or pu it inside the `if` condition like so:

```
<?php
include('check.php');
if(empty($_SESSION)){
    header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
} else {
    header("Location: http://example.com/admin.php");
}
?>
```

also make sure nothing is echoes /printed out in check.php as nothing should be echoed out before the header() function.

Comment: Doesn't fix my problem. Still not going to the location

Comment: @NielsvanderSchaaf are you getting any errors in your error log ?

Comment: @NielsvanderSchaaf include the following statement `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your script and you can view the errors.

Comment: Thanks for your tip of error reporting. Found a file were it already was been set. So editted it out of the file and now it's back working :D

Comment: @NielsvanderSchaaf great if the question helps you consider Approving / upvoting it .